# How does resampling audiofile to rate that is not a factor of the original rate or from lower to higher rate work?

Tags: audio, signal-processing

What I understand now is that, if I want to resample from 44100Hz to 22050Hz, I just have to take 1 sample and discard 1 sample for the entire sample.

However, I just wonder, for example,
if the recorded .wav is of 48000Hz sampling rate and I want to resample to 44100Hz. How does it work ?

1. resampling audiofile to rate that is not a factor of the original rate
2. resampling audiofile from lower to higher sampling rate

Comment: It's not a programming question perhaps (belongs to http://dsp.stackexchange.com/). ["Resampling" means combining interpolation and decimation to change the sampling rate by a rational factor.](http://dspguru.com/dsp/faqs/multirate/resampling) It's a process of identification of samples at new rate for the signal created/restored from given samples.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using any popular digital audio software like [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/)
Any conversion from higher [sampling rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_rate_conversion) to lower can be done.

You can use an application called `sox` like this:

```
sox file1.mpg -r 44100 file1-enc.mpg
```

Comment: Sorry I think I phrase the question wrongly. I want to know how it works.

Comment: Lower to higher can be done, but I don't think that it will improve quality. Think of sampling rate as resolution of any signal. Check this link <http://thestereobus.com/2008/01/12/sample-rate-and-bitrate-the-guts-of-digital-audio/>

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you should know that you can't go from 44100Hz to 22050Hz just by throwing away every other sample...

The sampling and resampling process is governed by the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem, which proves that a signal can be *perfectly reconstructed* by its samples at Fs Hz as long as it contains no content at frequencies >= Fs/2. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%2DShannon_sampling_theorem)

So, if you want to resample from 44100Hz down to 22050Hz, you must FIRST apply a filter to remove content at frequencies >= 11025Hz, and THEN you can discard every second sample.  The filtering step is required to create a signal that can be accurately represented with a 22050Hz sampling rate.

To go from, for example, 48000Hz to 44100Hz, the basic process is:

1. Add 146 zeros between every sample to get up to a sampling rate of 7.056MHz.  This creates a lot of content at frequencies > 24000Hz, but leaves content at frequencies < 24000Hz untouched.
2. Apply a low pass filter to filter out all content >= 22050Hz, to create a signal that can be accurately represented with a 44100Hz sampling rate.
3. Select every 160th sample of the filtered signal to get your 44100Hz sample stream.

That is the *basically* how it's done.  In real life some clever optimizations are implemented to make the process a lot faster, but mathematically it is exactly equivalent to the above steps.